# Partially blowing a motorcycle main fuse?

Tags: electrical, motorcycle

So in the continuing saga of my 81 Suzuki GL450L I have been making continuing improvements to the electrical. The coils as previously found were definitely an issue,  but possibly not 'the' issue.  While installing LED turn signals and relay everything went fine.. then a few minutes later I was totally without power. Not even the new low voltage signals.

I traced it all the way back to the main fuse.. when I wiggled it just right it let a little juice through, enough for the signals but not to turn her over. The fuse element  wasn't visible - the glass was cracked slightly and a bit smoked up. I bypassed with a bit of wire and things looked fine.

I could see a failure in the coils blow a fuse but this partiality failed behavior has me extra cautious... is there anything else I should check? I already covered the various sockets etc all looking for signs of heat damage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is standard in electrical work to consider one blown fuse an anomaly not worth investigating. However, if the replaced fuse blows, then investigate.

Of course, you should still do basic electrical inspections and repair anything questionable. In this case, maybe check connections and lead conditions.

Also: never, ever bypass a fuse. Not even for testing.